# Maven release plugin - Multi project with git submodules

Tags: java, git, maven

I just migrated some Java projects from Subversion to Git and did some cleaning up in the project structure.

Then, the project was in a repository and each subproject was just a subdirectory.

Now, each subproject has its own git repository and I created a parent project in another repository with git submodules pointing to the subprojects.

```
Demo
|->Sub1 (git submodule)
|  |->pom.xml
|->Sub2 (git submodule)
|  |->pom.xml
|->pom.xml
```

I just spent the day trying every possible configuration I could think of, but nothing seems to work. I either can't push the main repo (no-fast-forwards) or the subprojects don't get updated.

How can I configure `maven-release-plugin` to update the version numbers in all the submodules, create a tag on the main git repo and create the war artifacts, so I can then upload them with Jenkins?

Comment: This is not supported (yet)

Comment: Isn't there a way I can tinker something out ? Using preparationGoals, completionGoals or maybe some other parameter (commitByProject, pushChanges, ...)?

Comment: You're looking for https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-362 . The plugin is now designed to only release the root.